# How do you detect a jump in a curve, while ignoring noise?

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing

So I have a number of curves that may or may not present a certain feature. Here is an example of said feature:

[image]

The issue is that some curves either do not present this sudden step, or have noise of the same order of magnitude than what I'm trying to detect. Here are two problematic curves where problematic noise is highlighted in red and the feature I want to detect is in black (if present):

[image]

[image]

I have tried:

1. Using the ruptures package's implementation of the PELT algorithm. It fails because it neither return the correct index nor filters the noise
2. Using a running median filter, comparing the value of each new point entering the window to the median and selecting it based on the value of this difference. This fails because some noise has a magnitude of the same order as the step, and gets detected too. Plus, using a fixed threshold does not work since the size of the step varies even within one data sample.
3. Applying a savgol filter to the curve beforehand to remove the noise. This fails because it either softens the step at the same time, or does not soften the noise enough for it to get removed.

Does anyone has any idea?
Thanks :D

Comment: You could low-pass it to reduce any HF noise and then look at the first derivative at the areas that you've identified. If the sign flips, then you ignore it. You'll probably get some more robust suggestions at https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll give a look at that website too!